# Set id to newly created elements

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

This is mine first question, I'm glad to be part of this community.

Like I said in the title. I want to set ID to newly created elements. I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.

This is mine code sample:

```
function DataBack(response) {
var ci_output = document.getElementById('ci_output');
data = JSON.parse(response);
for (i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("p");
    li.setAttribute("id",'cmdbitem' + i);
    li.setAttribute('onclick', 'displayDetails(data.result[' + i + '])');
    document.getElementById('cmdbitem' + i).onclick = changeColor; //this function is throwing error "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"
    li.innerHTML = data.result[i].name;
    ci_output.appendChild(li);
    }
 }
```

What i want to achieve is to change color for newly created item which user click on. For this i need ID.
I made test and ID is set because e.g. this specific element is behave like it should

```
#cmdbitem2 {
cursor : pointer;
```

}

Why this document.getElementById('cmdbitem' + i).onclick = changeColor; is throwing an error ?

Thanks from advance.

Comment: you can directly use `li` here

Comment: can You give me the example of usage ?

Comment: `li` is (supposed to be) equal to `document.getElementById('cmdbitem' + i)` here. So simply write `li.onclick = changeColor;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the new element `li` is not inserted to document yet (which happends at `ci_output.appendChild(li);`).

but you can simply use `li` here, no need to get it though `getElementById`

---

Here is a complete example from your code.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
   let li = document.createElement("p")
   li.id = 'cmdbitem' + i
   li.addEventListener('click', ()=>displayDetails(data.result[i]))
   li.addEventListener('click', changeColor)
   li.innerHTML = data.result[i].name
   ci_output.appendChild(li)
}
```

---

some reference:

- [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (you can also use normal function)
- [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (**Always** use `let` instead of `var`)

Comment: Thanks for answer, can You tell me in witch way I can use it ?
li.onclick = cmdbitem[i].body.style.color = "purple"; 
something like this ?

Comment: @Hordii I add an example, note that I remove `setAttribute`, since there are better alternative for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is throwing an error because it couldnt find your element.

So lets go through your code:

- You create an element
- You search in the document for your element
- You add your element to the document

Notice how you searched the document for your element before you added it to the document?

`document.getElementById` searches through your document and not through all elements. Hope this helps! :D

EDIT: You can also just do `li.onclick`, this would be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can You tell me in witch way I can use it ? li.onclick = cmdbitem[i].body.style.color = "purple"; something like this ?